# NTLM access rights in PERL

Tags: windows, perl, ntlm

Is there a way to check if a user has access rights to a specific file in a network? I have the user name and the name of the file in a shared folder

Comment: What did you tried already? What platform/perl version will be used: Win32, linux or other?

Comment: I tried Win32 but I cannot access the file for some reason. Stat doesn't return anything either. I'm on Windows and using ActivePerl

Answer (score 0):

A cheap way is to use the SysInternals AccessChk tool, then parse the results.

There might be code in CPAN under the Win32:: namespace for checking access rights.